# How do I switch graphics?

Tags: windows-7, switchable-graphics

I have just installed  "[AMD Catalyst 12.3 RC](http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=358269)"

How do I switch to Intel graphics (e.g. disable ATI graphics)?

The weird thing is that the laptop fan is very quiet, which means one of two things: dynamic switching is now enabled (If that is a software thing, and *Catalyst 12.3* brought it); or the AMD graphics is disabled, but I don't see that in Driver Manager in Windows.

- Notebook Model: HP Dv6-6177ee
- GPU Models: AMD HD6770M + Intel HD3000
- OS: Windows 7 x64 Ultimate

Answer (score 1):

You should install the driver what your Vendor gave you. By vendor I mean HP. Look at HP's website. Check the support section. You should have some driver which lets you switch.

OR you can switch in the BIOS permanently.

Comment: Is there another solution? Do you have information on if AMD Catalyst now supports dynamic switching?

Comment: I have a switchable graphics card (Lenovo T500), same Intel/ATI combo. I can install the prop driver (I'm using that right now), but there is no way to switch them with the ATI driver on the fly. I usually reboot when I have to travel and switch to the Intel one. And when I'm on power, I just use the ATI one. The Lenovo driver is kinda buggy ... that's why I ditched it.